# Pen (codepen) not working when uploaded to server

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, rss

I have some code on codepen which is working fine as a pen. I needed to use that cpde, so I exported it as a .zip and tried to run it on a local server, which didn't work. I don't understand exactly why. All the dependencies are included in the html file since I chose to export as .zip, which does that automatically. Here is the code:

```js
$(function() {
  var $content = $('#jsonContent');
  var data = {
    rss_url: 'https://medium.com/feed/@SwachhCoin'
  };
  $.get('https://api.rss2json.com/v1/api.json', data, function(response) {
    if (response.status == 'ok') {
      var output = '';
      $.each(response.items, function(k, item) {
        var visibleSm;
        if (k < 3) {
          visibleSm = '';
        } else {
          visibleSm = ' visible-sm';
        }
        output += '<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4' + visibleSm + '">';
        output += '<div class="blog-post"><header>';
        output += '<h4 class="date">' + $.format.date(item.pubDate, "dd<br>MMM") + "</h4>";
        var tagIndex = item.description.indexOf('<img'); // Find where the img tag starts
        var srcIndex = item.description.substring(tagIndex).indexOf('src=') + tagIndex; // Find where the src attribute starts
        var srcStart = srcIndex + 5; // Find where the actual image URL starts; 5 for the length of 'src="'
        var srcEnd = item.description.substring(srcStart).indexOf('"') + srcStart; // Find where the URL ends
        var src = item.description.substring(srcStart, srcEnd); // Extract just the URL
        output += '<div class="blog-element"><img class="img-responsive col-12" src="' + src + '" style="padding:1px!important"></div></header>';
        output += '<div class="blog-content"><h4><a href="' + item.link + '">' + item.title + '</a></h4>';
        output += '<div class="post-meta"><span>By ' + item.author + '</span></div>';
        var yourString = item.description.replace(/<img[^>]*>/g, ""); //replace with your string.
        var maxLength = 120 // maximum number of characters to extract
        //trim the string to the maximum length
        var trimmedString = yourString.substr(0, maxLength);
        //re-trim if we are in the middle of a word
        trimmedString = trimmedString.substr(0, Math.min(trimmedString.length, trimmedString.lastIndexOf(" ")))
        output += '<p>' + trimmedString + '...</p>';
        output += '</div></div></div>';
        return k < 3;
      });
      $content.html(output);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
.blog .blog-post {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.blog .blog-post header {
  position: relative;
}

.blog .blog-post header .date {
  background-color: #55ff63;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 500;
  z-index: 9;
  color: #2c2c2c;
}

.blog .blog-post .blog-content {
  padding: 15px 28px;
  border: 1px solid #f5f5f5;
  background: #444;
}

.blog .blog-post .blog-content h4 {
  margin: 20px 0;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.blog .blog-post .blog-content h4 a {
  color: white;
}

.blog .blog-post .blog-content .post-meta {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 18px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #F5F5F5;
}

.blog .blog-post .blog-content .post-meta span {
  color: #CCC;
}

.blog .blog-post .blog-content .post-meta span:first-child a {
  color: #848484;
}

.blog .blog-post .blog-content .post-meta span a {
  color: #CCC;
  border-bottom: 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.blog .blog-post .blog-content .post-meta span a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-color: inherit;
}

.blog .blog-post .blog-content .post-meta span {
  padding-right: 10px;
  border-right: 1px solid #CCC;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.blog .blog-post .blog-content .post-meta span:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
  border-right: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}

.blog .blog-post .blog-content p {
  color: lightgrey;
  line-height: 22px;
}

.blog .blog-post footer {
  border: 1px solid #DDD;
  padding: 0px 15px;
}

.blog .blog-post footer .comment-count {
  color: #000;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 25px;
}

.blog .blog-post footer .comment-count:hover,
.blog .blog-post footer .comment-count:focus {
  color: #000;
}

.blog .blog-post footer .read-more {
  color: #000;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.blog .blog-post footer .read-more:hover,
.blog .blog-post footer .read-more:focus {
  color: #000;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .blog .blog-post header .image-slider-carousel .carousel-control.left {
    top: 200px;
    bottom: 5px;
    left: 220px;
  }
  .blog .blog-post header .image-slider-carousel .carousel-control.right {
    top: 200px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .blog .blog-post header .image-slider-carousel .carousel-control.left {
    top: 210px;
    bottom: 5px;
    left: 235px;
  }
  .blog .blog-post header .image-slider-carousel .carousel-control.right {
    top: 210px;
    right: 10px;
    bottom: 5px;
  }
}

.blog-standard .blog-post {
  margin-bottom: 80px;
}

.blog-standard .blog-post:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.blog-standard .blog-post .featured-image {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.blog-standard .blog-post .post-title {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.blog-standard .blog-post .post-title>a {
  color: #5c5c5c;
}

.blog-standard .blog-post .post-title>a:hover {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.blog-standard .blog-post .post-meta {
  color: silver;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 11px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.blog-standard .blog-post .post-meta a {
  color: #656565;
}

.blog-standard .blog-post .post-meta span {
  margin: 0 6px;
}

.blog-standard .blog-post .read-more {
  margin-top: 25px;
}

.blog-standard .blog-post .read-more a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: black;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.blog-standard .blog-post .read-more a:hover {
  color: silver;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/*overriding bootstrap's default pagination */

.pagination-lg>li:last-child>a,
.pagination-lg>li:last-child>span {
  border-top-right-radius: 2px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 2px;
}

.pagination-lg>li:first-child>a,
.pagination-lg>li:first-child>span {
  border-top-left-radius: 2px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 2px;
}

.pagination>li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 8px;
}

.pagination>.active>a,
.pagination>.active>span,
.pagination>.active>a:hover,
.pagination>.active>span:hover,
.pagination>.active>a:focus,
.pagination>.active>span:focus {
  background-color: black;
  border-color: black;
}

.pagination>li>a,
.pagination>li>span {
  color: #909090;
}

.sidebar {
  padding: 0 0 0 30px;
}

.sidebar .widget {
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}

.sidebar .widget.popular-posts .widget-content ul {
  padding: 15px 0 0 0;
  list-style: none;
  color: #b0b0b0;
}

.sidebar .widget.popular-posts .widget-content ul li {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.sidebar .widget.popular-posts .widget-content ul .thumb {
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-top: -10px;
}

.sidebar .widget.popular-posts .widget-content ul .title {
  color: gray;
}

.sidebar .widget.popular-tags a {
  margin-bottom: 6px;
}

.sidebar .widget.categories ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.sidebar .widget.categories ul li {
  line-height: 3em;
}

.sidebar .widget.categories ul li:before {
  content: "";
  font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.sidebar .widget.categories ul li a {
  color: black;
}

.sidebar .widget.categories ul li a:hover {
  color: gray;
}

.left-sidebar .sidebar {
  padding: 0 30px 0 0;
}

.blog-grid .blog-element {
  max-height: 290px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.blog-grid .blog-element img {
  width: 100%;
}

figcaption {
  color: #95989a;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://c72e469f272d443e85fba9d21d04cd33.production.codepen.plumbing/jQuery-dateFormat.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- Blog-->
<section class="section blog" id="blog">
  <div class="container">
    <!---->
    <header class="section-heading">
      <h2>From The Blog</h2><span>Awesome articles from the blog</span>
    </header>
    <!---->
    <div class="section-content" id="blogContent">
      <div class="row" id="jsonContent"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- /#blogContent-->
    <div class="text-center"><a class="btn btn-dark" id="loadBlogPosts" href="//medium.com/@SwachhCoin">View All<span class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></span></a></div>
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-->
</section>
<!-- Blog-->
```

And here is the actual pen:

https://codepen.io/arkonique/full/NyZZBw/

Comment: What do you mean *doesn't work*? Is there an error?

Comment: See the code snippet. That is the error I am getting in the console

Comment: I was also getting a 403 error for jquery-dateFormat.js, so I changed the source for it, but it still didn't work

Comment: `jquery-dateFormat.js` is not linked properly. Don't use codepen url. It don't support outside codepen. Try to call the original link or save the js inside a local file and give the path to that. Then it will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The production cdn was not available.
Also you need to change jquery to be loaded before date-format

```js
$(function() {
  var $content = $('#jsonContent');
  var data = {
    rss_url: 'https://medium.com/feed/@SwachhCoin'
  };
  $.get('https://api.rss2json.com/v1/api.json', data, function(response) {
    if (response.status == 'ok') {
      var output = '';
      $.each(response.items, function(k, item) {
        var visibleSm;
        if (k < 3) {
          visibleSm = '';
        } else {
          visibleSm = ' visible-sm';
        }
        output += '<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4' + visibleSm + '">';
        output += '<div class="blog-post"><header>';
        output += '<h4 class="date">' + $.format.date(item.pubDate, "dd<br>MMM") + "</h4>";
        var tagIndex = item.description.indexOf('<img'); // Find where the img tag starts
        var srcIndex = item.description.substring(tagIndex).indexOf('src=') + tagIndex; // Find where the src attribute starts
        var srcStart = srcIndex + 5; // Find where the actual image URL starts; 5 for the length of 'src="'
        var srcEnd = item.description.substring(srcStart).indexOf('"') + srcStart; // Find where the URL ends
        var src = item.description.substring(srcStart, srcEnd); // Extract just the URL
        output += '<div class="blog-element"><img class="img-responsive col-12" src="' + src + '" style="padding:1px!important"></div></header>';
        output += '<div class="blog-content"><h4><a href="' + item.link + '">' + item.title + '</a></h4>';
        output += '<div class="post-meta"><span>By ' + item.author + '</span></div>';
        var yourString = item.description.replace(/<img[^>]*>/g, ""); //replace with your string.
        var maxLength = 120 // maximum number of characters to extract
        //trim the string to the maximum length
        var trimmedString = yourString.substr(0, maxLength);
        //re-trim if we are in the middle of a word
        trimmedString = trimmedString.substr(0, Math.min(trimmedString.length, trimmedString.lastIndexOf(" ")))
        output += '<p>' + trimmedString + '...</p>';
        output += '</div></div></div>';
        return k < 3;
      });
      $content.html(output);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
.blog .blog-post {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.blog .blog-post header {
  position: relative;
}

.blog .blog-post header .date {
  background-color: #55ff63;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 500;
  z-index: 9;
  color: #2c2c2c;
}

.blog .blog-post .blog-content {
  padding: 15px 28px;
  border: 1px solid #f5f5f5;
  background: #444;
}

.blog .blog-post .blog-content h4 {
  margin: 20px 0;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.blog .blog-post .blog-content h4 a {
  color: white;
}

.blog .blog-post .blog-content .post-meta {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 18px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #F5F5F5;
}

.blog .blog-post .blog-content .post-meta span {
  color: #CCC;
}

.blog .blog-post .blog-content .post-meta span:first-child a {
  color: #848484;
}

.blog .blog-post .blog-content .post-meta span a {
  color: #CCC;
  border-bottom: 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.blog .blog-post .blog-content .post-meta span a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-color: inherit;
}

.blog .blog-post .blog-content .post-meta span {
  padding-right: 10px;
  border-right: 1px solid #CCC;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.blog .blog-post .blog-content .post-meta span:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
  border-right: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}

.blog .blog-post .blog-content p {
  color: lightgrey;
  line-height: 22px;
}

.blog .blog-post footer {
  border: 1px solid #DDD;
  padding: 0px 15px;
}

.blog .blog-post footer .comment-count {
  color: #000;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 25px;
}

.blog .blog-post footer .comment-count:hover,
.blog .blog-post footer .comment-count:focus {
  color: #000;
}

.blog .blog-post footer .read-more {
  color: #000;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.blog .blog-post footer .read-more:hover,
.blog .blog-post footer .read-more:focus {
  color: #000;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .blog .blog-post header .image-slider-carousel .carousel-control.left {
    top: 200px;
    bottom: 5px;
    left: 220px;
  }
  .blog .blog-post header .image-slider-carousel .carousel-control.right {
    top: 200px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .blog .blog-post header .image-slider-carousel .carousel-control.left {
    top: 210px;
    bottom: 5px;
    left: 235px;
  }
  .blog .blog-post header .image-slider-carousel .carousel-control.right {
    top: 210px;
    right: 10px;
    bottom: 5px;
  }
}

.blog-standard .blog-post {
  margin-bottom: 80px;
}

.blog-standard .blog-post:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.blog-standard .blog-post .featured-image {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.blog-standard .blog-post .post-title {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.blog-standard .blog-post .post-title>a {
  color: #5c5c5c;
}

.blog-standard .blog-post .post-title>a:hover {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.blog-standard .blog-post .post-meta {
  color: silver;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 11px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.blog-standard .blog-post .post-meta a {
  color: #656565;
}

.blog-standard .blog-post .post-meta span {
  margin: 0 6px;
}

.blog-standard .blog-post .read-more {
  margin-top: 25px;
}

.blog-standard .blog-post .read-more a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: black;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.blog-standard .blog-post .read-more a:hover {
  color: silver;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/*overriding bootstrap's default pagination */

.pagination-lg>li:last-child>a,
.pagination-lg>li:last-child>span {
  border-top-right-radius: 2px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 2px;
}

.pagination-lg>li:first-child>a,
.pagination-lg>li:first-child>span {
  border-top-left-radius: 2px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 2px;
}

.pagination>li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 8px;
}

.pagination>.active>a,
.pagination>.active>span,
.pagination>.active>a:hover,
.pagination>.active>span:hover,
.pagination>.active>a:focus,
.pagination>.active>span:focus {
  background-color: black;
  border-color: black;
}

.pagination>li>a,
.pagination>li>span {
  color: #909090;
}

.sidebar {
  padding: 0 0 0 30px;
}

.sidebar .widget {
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}

.sidebar .widget.popular-posts .widget-content ul {
  padding: 15px 0 0 0;
  list-style: none;
  color: #b0b0b0;
}

.sidebar .widget.popular-posts .widget-content ul li {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.sidebar .widget.popular-posts .widget-content ul .thumb {
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-top: -10px;
}

.sidebar .widget.popular-posts .widget-content ul .title {
  color: gray;
}

.sidebar .widget.popular-tags a {
  margin-bottom: 6px;
}

.sidebar .widget.categories ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.sidebar .widget.categories ul li {
  line-height: 3em;
}

.sidebar .widget.categories ul li:before {
  content: "";
  font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.sidebar .widget.categories ul li a {
  color: black;
}

.sidebar .widget.categories ul li a:hover {
  color: gray;
}

.left-sidebar .sidebar {
  padding: 0 30px 0 0;
}

.blog-grid .blog-element {
  max-height: 290px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.blog-grid .blog-element img {
  width: 100%;
}

figcaption {
  color: #95989a;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-dateFormat/1.0/jquery.dateFormat.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- Blog-->
<section class="section blog" id="blog">
  <div class="container">
    <!---->
    <header class="section-heading">
      <h2>From The Blog</h2><span>Awesome articles from the blog</span>
    </header>
    <!---->
    <div class="section-content" id="blogContent">
      <div class="row" id="jsonContent"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- /#blogContent-->
    <div class="text-center"><a class="btn btn-dark" id="loadBlogPosts" href="//medium.com/@SwachhCoin">View All<span class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></span></a></div>
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-->
</section>
<!-- Blog-->
```

Comment: I tried changing the cdn but it did't work. I think I was loading jquery after dateformat. Thanks.